# Grails Mail plugin not working

Tags: grails, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send mails from a Grails application, but without any success.

I've used gmail and other smtp server (without ssl!) but the same error occurs:

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?; message exceptions (1) are:
Failed message 1: javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

I am using in Config.groovy (example for gmail):

```
grails.mail.host = "smtp.gmail.com"
grails.mail.from = "xxx@gmail.com"
grails.mail.port = "465"
grails.mail.ssl = "on"
grails.mail.username = "xxx@gmail.com"
grails.mail.password = "xxx"
grails.mail.props = ["mail.smtp.auth": "true",
        "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port": "465",
        "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class": "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
        "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback": "false",
        "mail.smtp.starttls.enable": "true",
        "mail.debug": "true"]
```

EDIT: I made a simple app with just the mail plugin and a controller and the config posted by Javid Jamae works (3rd answer, also I think the other should work).

BUT even if I just copy-paste the same config and the same sending mail code, on my primary project it still gives me the same exception! I think this can be caused by Nimble plugin (Mail plugin was installed by it).
My configuration is:
Grails version: 1.3.4
Groovy version: 1.7.4
JVM version: 1.6.0_21
jquery - 1.4.2.5
mail - 0.9
shiro - 1.0.1
nimble - 0.4-SNAPSHOT

**FINAL EDIT :**
I resolved the issue: it seems that I have to use the same settings in the Nimble plugin also, in NimbleConfig.groovy -> mail { ...  (must have "from = ...") } .
Stupid issue, but waisted a lot of time on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not using SSL and I have the following defined at the bottom of my Config.groovy (not under the environments section):

```
grails {
   mail {
     host = "smtp.gmail.com"
     port = 465
     username = "xxx@gmail.com"
     password = "xxx"
     props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",                     
              "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
              "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
              "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
   }
}
```

I'm using:

```
app.grails.version=1.2.1
plugins.mail=0.9
```

This works for me.

Comment: I'm closing this thread. I didn't find a solution but I see that the question is too old and nobody answer anymore.

Comment: This does not works for me. I am getting this error -- `unable to find valid certification path to requested target`. Please check my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547949/grails-send-mail-is-not-working)..

Answer (score 3):

You have enabled SSL:

> grails.mail.ssl = "on"

And got exception

> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?.

So disable SSL (my config):

```
host = "smtp.gmail.com"
port = 465
username = "username@gmail.com"
password = "password"
javaMailProperties = ['mail.smtp.auth': 'true',
        'mail.smtp.socketFactory.port': '465',
        'mail.smtp.socketFactory.class': 'javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory',
        'mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback': 'false']
```

Anyway, if you want to enable SSL - try **587** port.

Also try to set

> mail.smtp.starttls.required : 'true'

Because if server not supports secure connection or client doesn't accept server's certificate secure connection will not started and you will got your exception.
But after setting starttls.required = true and secure connection is impossible whole connection will fails so you got proper exception message.

P.S. Take a note that SSL and TLS - is different protocols.

Comment: Same Exception after trying what you said. I did tried port 587 and not using ssl="on" before posting here on stackoverflow. Something is very wrong and I curious if somebody else had this issue before.

Comment: @cripox did you try removing the quotes from your port as I suggested? I am running an application using the config below and it works fine

Comment: unfortunately is still not working- tried from home computer and also deployed on a vps

Comment: have you tried mail.smtp.starttls.required : 'true' ? and does it changed the exception message ?

Comment: @Olexandr : yes, I tried also with starttls.required:"true" but the Exception is the same

Answer (score 1):

I dont have this line in my configuration

```
"mail.smtp.starttls.enable": "true"
```

and my connection is working

also the port should not be in quotes

```
grails.mail.port = 465
```

Comment: still the same exception even without this line.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Not getting success yet. See my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547949/grails-send-mail-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar strain of this issue as well, so I'll share my experience. When using the Nimble plugin (which uses the Mail plugin as a dependency), Nimble defines its own mail settings in `grails-app/conf/NimbleConfig.groovy`.

The settings in `NimbleConfig.groovy` appear to overwrite those set in `Config.groovy` (presumably because `NimbleConfig` is executed after `Config`).

The solution here is conditional:

- **If you're using Nimble**, set the mail properties in `grails-app/conf/NimbleConfig.groovy`; you do not need to set them in `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy`
- **If you're not using Nimble**, then just follow the Mail plugin instructions for configuration (or use Javid Jamae's answer)

This seems to be what the OP alluded to in his/her edits, but I just thought I'd confirm the edits with my understanding of what's happening.

*Update:*

For a reference, here are the `NimbleConfig.groovy` settings that worked for me:

```
nimble {
    ...
    messaging {
        ...
        mail {
            host = 'smtp.gmail.com'
            port = 465
            username = '...@gmail.com'
            password = '...'
            props = [
                'mail.smtp.auth': 'true',
                'mail.smtp.socketFactory.port': '465',
                'mail.smtp.socketFactory.class': 'javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory',
                'mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback': 'false'
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I found myself a lot of tweaks around, but in the end I just gave up on using Nimble. The plugin is wonderful but I kept getting a lot of errors like this because of it (the mail was just one of it, there also is the bootstrap issue, and a lot of issues trying to deploy). So, anyway for what I wanted it was too overkill and too big, so I just written my own code. Too bad because it is a nice written plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify your config settings at runtime by checking the 
mailService.mailSender properties.Something like this: 
mailService.mailSender.properties.each{println} 
It will yield the host, port, username, password and a few other values. 
If you're sure they are all correct, I would suspect a firewall issue.