# How to upgrade Grails version from 2.1.2 to 2.2.3 in Ubuntu

Tags: grails, ubuntu, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I am new in Linux. I am using Ubuntu to install Grails. I am following this command --

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:groovy-dev/grails
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grails-ppa
```

But When I try to install Grails 2.2.3 it automatically load 2.1.2 version.

```
sudo apt-get install grails 2.2.3
```

When I run this command, it install grails 2.1.2 version. I am not getting any idea how to upgrade my grails version to 2.2.3.

I am using `java-6-openjdk-amd64` because java-7 is giving H2 db error with grails 2.1.2

Please help...

Comment: You may use oracle-jdk instead of openjdk and gvmtool

Comment: Yes May be you are right because When I am using gvm tool to upgrade my grails to 2.2.3 then its not working with both `java-6-openjdk-amd64` and `java-7-openjdk-amd64`. Showing same error `Could not determine Hibernate dialect for database name [H2]!`. I will try to change my java to oracle-jdk.

Comment: I installed `oracle jdk-7u25-linux-x64.tar.gz` and it works fine with `Grails 2.2.3`. I am surprised why `Open-JDK7` does not work with `Grails 2.2.3`. Anyway Now I am not getting `Could not determine Hibernate dialect for database name [H2]!` error. Check [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7) to install `Oracle JDK 7`

Comment: Another time you can use ppa with oracle jdk 

https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/java

http://www.unixmen.com/howto-install-oracle-java-7-jdk-jre-in-ubuntu-12-10-quantal-quetzal-ppa/

It is more simple :)

Comment: @baxxabit, yes PPA is also a good way to download oracle jdk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the PPA currently (19th July 2013) only goes up to 2.2.0.  If you want a later version you'll need to download the [standard zip distribution](http://grails.org/download) or use a tool like [GVM](http://gvmtool.net/) rather than installing using apt-get.

Comment: I am completely new to Linux. Can Grails Zip works in Linux if I set environment variable ???

Comment: And How to uninstall grails-ppa and my all old version grails ??

Comment: @ShreshttBhatt Grails will work fine if you simply unpack the zip file, add the grails `bin` directory to your `PATH` and make sure `JAVA_HOME` is set correctly.  A simple `apt-get remove grails` should be enough to uninstall the PPA version if you need to, but there's no reason why you can't have several different versions of Grails installed at the same time for different applications as long as you run the right version for each app.  This is what GVM helps automate.

Comment: Can you check my another Stack-overflow [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547949/grails-send-mail-is-not-working) ??

Comment: Yes, the PPA is deprecated in favor of GVM.  GVM does this quite well and cross platform.

Answer (score 6):

Install `GVM`

```
sudo apt get install curl 

curl -s get.gvmtool.net | bash
```

restart terminal , then :

```
gvm install grails 2.2.3
gvm use grails 2.2.3
```

if you want  permanently use a version, instead of `gvm use` run `gvm default` ;

```
gvm default grails 2.2.3
```